# I unable to get json result when i use webservice to get data

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services

I need to display id from customer table using webservice but i can't get it using belove code.

Response get in browser console.
[image: get json result]

This is my ajax call to get or display whole result but its not working to get customer id

```js
     $(document).ready(function () {
                var values;
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://localhost:53562/WebService.asmx/HelloWorld',                
                    type: 'POST',               
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert("ajax call");
                        //$.map(data, function (product) {
                        //    alert(product.Id);
                        //    $('<tr> <td>' + product.Name + '</td> <td>' + product.ProductNumber + ' </td> <td>' + product.SafetyStockLevel + ' </td> <td>' + product.ReorderPoint + ' </td></tr>').appendTo(".tblData");
                        //});
                        //for (var i in data) {
                        //    alert(data[i]);
                        //    // data[i].something, etc
                        //}
                        //var datas=data.par                   
                        $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                            alert(item);
                        });
                    }
                  
                });
            });
```

```
This is my webservice code to get customer id from database and convert result to json and return this result to json call.
```

```
    [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            // getting connection string
            string conStr = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbConection"].ConnectionString;

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conStr))
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Id from customer", conn);
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dt);
                System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serilizer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
                List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
                Dictionary<string, object> row;
                foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                    foreach(DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                    {
                        row.Add(col.ColumnName,dr[col]);                
                    }
                    rows.Add(row);                
                }
                return serilizer.Serialize(rows);   
            }
```

Comment: Could you pls add a `console.log(data)` inside the `success` function and post what you are getting in console?

Comment: Please paste the response as text rather than as an image as those with smaller monitors (or on mobile browsers) will find it hard to read.

Comment: Since you are using `JavaScriptSerializer` I think you might be getting response data as `data.d` but just wanted to confirm before posting the answer.

Comment: palash i get perfect result in console.log(data) but there is problem to display this result

Comment: `console.log(data);` Is it a string or is it an object?

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN docs:

[Serialize(Object) :    Converts an object to a JSON string.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx)

That seems to be a json string not a valid json, so in this case you have to parse it before you loop through each object in the response:

```
var resp = JSON.parse(data); // converts a json string to a valid json object
$.each(resp, function (index, item) { // use var resp in here 
    alert(item.id);
});
```

Comment: Not working at all... even parsing like data.responceJSON is not working.

Comment: `success: function (data) {` have you parsed this `data` or `data.responseJSON` because as per your response img there is no key named `responseJSON`. But the fact is if you have a successful ajax response then in the success function the arg name `data` is the actual response you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should specify wich kind of data you're getting from the ajax request, since it seems like it's being read as a string.
To your ajax request options, try to add:

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```